# elements are not handling by using jsoup

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

my Html file is look like this:

```
<div class="mdt">
  Samsung Galaxy Y S5360
</div>
<div class="mdt">
  Samsung Champ Neo Duos C3262
</div>
<div class="mdt">
  Micromax Ninja A27
</div>
<div class="mdt">
  Karbonn S1 Titanium
</div>

<div class="priceDiv discTop">
  <span class="WebRupee WebRupeeMain">Rs.</span> 5,717
</div>
<div class="priceDiv discTop">
  <span class="WebRupee WebRupeeMain">Rs.</span> 3,004
</div>
<div class="priceDiv discTop">
  <span class="WebRupee WebRupeeMain">Rs.</span> 3,348
</div>
<div class="priceDiv discTop">
  <span class="WebRupee WebRupeeMain">Rs.</span> 9,306
</div>
```

I want to display the out put is ::

```
 Samsung Galaxy Y S5360    Rs. 5,717 

 Samsung Champ Neo Duos C3262   Rs. 3,004 

 Micromax Ninja A27    Rs. 3,348
```

for this i am using Jsoup Elements class. My actual code is :

```
doc.select("body").select("table").select("div.mdt")
```

and

```
doc.select("body").select("table").select("div.priceDiv.discTop")
```

by using this code, i am able to display individually. i used two for loops to iterate both
...

Answer (score 0):

I don'k know about Jsoup, but i can show how i can do it in java.

So you'll catch all the phones and prices and put it into a list.

```
List<WebElement> allPhones = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.mdt"));
List<WebElement> allPrices = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.priceDiv.discTop"));
```

since you have all that you can easily do that

```
for (int i = 0; i < allPhones.length; i++) {
  Systeme.out.println(allphones.get(i).getText() + " " + allPrices.get(i).getText());           
}
```